# Android SQLite delete single contact

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi I am new to coding and new to StackOverFlow

I am studying Android at uni. I have created an App using Android and SQLite.
I am trying to delete a single contact in my SQLite Database. It is in a ListFragment and I am attempting to delete a single contact in a onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) method.

I cannot see what I have done wrong is anyone able to give me a pointer as to what I must do to delete a single contact? Thanks in advance.

### ListFragment Inventory_List

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    DBAdapter dba2 = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    dba2.open();
    dba2.deleteContact((int) getSelectedItemId());
    dba2.close();
    //MainActivity.entries.clear(); //deletes all entries in the database.

    return true;
}
```

### DBAdapter

```
//---deletes a particular contact---
public boolean deleteContact(int rowId)
{
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) > 0;
}
```

The items in my Database DBAdapter class are:

```
static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_INVOICE = "invoice";
static final String KEY_QUALITY ="quality";
static final String KEY_DATE ="date";
static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";
static final String KEY_APPLICATION="application";
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contact";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String DATABASE_CREATE =


//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
//---closes the database---
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
```

Please let me know if I have missed providing something.
Thanks again.

Comment: The deleteAll method works. and deletes all entries but the deleteContact method does not work.

Comment: Currently is deleting all entries, every row.

Comment: `MainActivity.entries.clear();` clear all entries

Comment: You are right MainActivity.entries.clear(); is actually deleting all the rows in my database. I have edited the code above. Does anyone know how I delete a single contact?

Comment: I'd suggest checking two things a) **the value returned from `getSelectedItemId`** and b) **the value returned from from the call to the `deleteContact` method**. You'd want the value returned by getSelectedItemId to **match a row's _id column value**. You'd want **true** to be returned from the deleteContact.  I'd suspect that your issue is likely with the `getSelectedItemId` method not returning a suitable value and thus there is no row to be deleted and thus no row is deleted.

Comment: Hi MikeT I have looked at the value returned by getSelectedItemId() and have added +1 so that the rowID will be 1 instead of 0, when trying to delete the first value. It did not work. Is there something wrong with my deleteContact() method? it does not delete anything now that i have commented out //MainActivity.entries.clear();